# Query Not Working When Moved to Function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query on index.php page that works perfectly. But when I move the query over to functions.php, create the the exact same query, it breaks. Any idea why?

index.php

```
<ul>
 <?php $cms_sub_pages = cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name); ?>
 <?php while($subpage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cms_sub_pages)) { ?>
   <li><a href="/edit.php?
       <?php echo $subpage["page_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $subpage["link_name"]; ?></a
   </li>    
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <?php mysqli_free_result($sub_pages); ?>
 </ul>
```

functions.php

```
function cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name) {
    global $conn;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE main_cat = 2 AND category =  '{$file_name}' ORDER BY subcategory_order ASC ";
    $sub_pages = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    confirm_query($sub_pages);
    return $sub_pages;  
}
```

SOLVED: The issue was in index.php here:

```
<?php $cms_sub_pages = cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name); ?>
```

Changed to:

```
<?php $cms_sub_pages = cms_find_sub_pages ($mainpage["page_id"]); ?>
```

Comment: where you defined this variable .`$file_name`

Comment: I updated code, copied wrong line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Undefined variable $file_name.

Use

```
function cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name) {
```

OR

```
function cms_find_sub_pages () {
    global $conn, $file_name;
```

Please, use error_reporting(E_ALL); from header.php for debug your scripts.

P.S. Sorry my english

Comment: Thanks, yes, I did that as you can see from my edits. I still get an error.

Comment: Use <?php $cms_sub_pages = cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name); ?>

Comment: Variable $file_name from script `<ul>
 <?php $cms_sub_pages = cms_find_sub_pages ($file_name); ?>
 <?php while($subpage = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cms_sub_pages)) { ?>
   <li><a href="/edit.php?
       <?php echo $subpage["page_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $subpage["link_name"]; ?></a
   </li>    
 <?php
 }
 ?>
 <?php mysqli_free_result($sub_pages); ?>
 </ul>` is defined?